# How do I increase Alpha in UIAlertAction?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

When I use AlertControlAction it  takes over the screen until you press cancel or whatnot.

I want to know is there is a way to increase the Alpha of the grey section around it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can setting the alpha as per your need, which will cause some transparency in any case.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert title" message:@"Alert message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
[alertController addAction:ok];

alertController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.6];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: The question is about `UIAlertController`, not `UIActionSheet`.

Comment: You still need to remove the bad part of the answer.

Comment: No, you still haven't removed the wrong part of your answer (the part before "For UIAlertController").

Comment: @rmaddy now is it ok ?

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this by doing this:

```swift
class AlertController: UIAlertController{
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.presentingViewController?.view.alpha = 1     
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.presentingViewController?.view.alpha = 0.5
    } 
}
```